# Writing stacked hats on a character with subscripts

Tags: accents

As part of writing up notes I need to write something containing subscript and two "hats", however having a look online i can find only people doing it by manually positioning them which is a little beyond me given I've been using latex for 4 days.

What I am trying to write is something I thought would be achieved with:

```
\begin{equation}
\dot{\tilde c_{21}}
\end{equation}
```

However when outputting this becomes garbled. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  although your question is reasonably clear, it would be much easier for us to help if you provide a small compilable example that shows what you have done.  potential helpers can cut and paste that example and use it to experiment.

Comment: I tried to with \begin{equation} \dot{\tilde c_{21}} \end{equation} but i'll write something a bit clearer

Comment: please start your example with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.  (that's what i meant by "compilable".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\dot{\tilde c_{21}}`, you should write

```
\dot{\tilde{c}}_{21}
```

That way, you inform TeX that the dot and tilde diacritics are supposed to be applied to `c`, and not to `c_{21}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\dot{\tilde{c}}_{21} \quad \dot{\tilde c_{21}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you. I wouldn't have thought it would be a problem to apply it to the whole thing but i guess that's just beginner ignorance aha

Comment: To the downvoter: Please enlighten me as to what's objectionable about this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your command nesting was a bid odd (if you really want that it could be arranged but might need some manual adjustment of the accent positions) but the two normal arrangements work fine

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\dot{\tilde{{c_{21}}}} +  \dot{\tilde{c}}_{21}
\]
\end{document}
```