# Renumbering chapter after part, include part number as suffix in cross-reference to chapter number

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

i want to do the same like in this answered question:

[Renumbering chapter after part, correct ref, ToC and chap header aspect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240506/renumbering-chapter-after-part-correct-ref-toc-and-chap-header-aspect)

which gives the following code to add:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand{\p@chapter}{\thepart.}
\makeatother
```

with one difference:

Is it possible to add the part-"part" *after* the chapter-"part" inside the cross-reference?

What I mean is, is it possible to set a suffix?

The result should for:

```
Comparison between \autoref{part_1_chapter_1} and \autoref{part_2_chapter_1}
```

should look somehow like:

> Comparison between Chapter 1/Part I and Chapter 1/Part II

UPDATE:

I want to be able to ref to any command like chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection and have the normal output of autoref and after this there should be added the part from this ref.

For example:

Chapter 1/Part 1 or Section 2/Part 1

Comment: You mention `\autoref` -- would you be OK with `\cref` (from the `cleveref` package) as well?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347266/cross-reference-differently-depending-on-whether-we-are-in-the-same-part-chapter/347271?s=19|0.0000#347271 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312060/how-to-reference-sections-in-other-parts-mentioning-the-part/347161?s=20|0.0000#347161

Comment: Well Cleverref seem to be able to do the same,

Comment: @duichwer: Do you need the names with the first character in upper case letter, i.e. Chapter, Section, Equation etc.?

Comment: @duichwer: See the update please!

Comment: A similar approach can be found in my answer to this question here, although the background is different: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353491/how-to-show-also-the-name-of-the-parent-counter-with-cleveref

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a an approach (similar to Mico's answer) with `zref` and storing the part information with `\zlabel` instead of `\label`.

The solution stores anchors and the type of the counter being referenced. 
It retrieves the counter name, changes the name to have the first letter being upper case and types this new name together with the part info.

If the part counter is used or the reference is not made with `zlabel`, the `\pref` command falls back to `\Cref`.

The precise format of the output can be configured within `\partreferenceformat`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[user,counter,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_tail:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_uppercase:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn {Nx}

\newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]{%
  \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str {#1}%
  \str_uppercase:x {\str_head:N \l_tmpa_str}\str_tail:V {\l_tmpa_str}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\makeatletter


\newif\if@hyperrefloaded
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \global\@hyperrefloadedtrue
  }{
    \global\@hyperrefloadedfalse
  }
}


\zref@newprop{partinfo}{\thepart}
\zref@addprop{main}{partinfo}

\newcommand{\partreferenceformat}[1]{%
  \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}}\ \zref@extract{#1}{default}/Part \zref@extract{#1}{partinfo}%
}

\newcommand{\pref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp@@a{part}%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \Cref{#1}%
  }{%
    % Checking whether we have a reference to the part counter -> use the usual \Cref for this
    \edef\temp@@b{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}}%
    \ifx\temp@@b\temp@@a
    \Cref{#1}%
    \else
    \if@hyperrefloaded
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\partreferenceformat{#1}}%
    \else
    \partreferenceformat{#1}%
    \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\part{AAA}    
\chapter{Uno} \zlabel{chap:uno}

\section{Foo section} \zlabel{sec:foo}
\part{BBB}    \label{part:bbb}
\chapter{Due} \zlabel{chap:due}
\blindtext[5]

\clearpage


A comparison between \pref{chap:uno} and \pref{chap:due} or \pref{sec:foo} \dots

On the other hand \pref{part:bbb} produces something different!

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Old solution**

The command `\chappartref` retrieves the label and checks whether it is a label belonging to the chapter counter, otherwise it falls back to `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[user,counter,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{partinfo}{\thepart}
\zref@addprop{main}{partinfo}

\newcommand{\chappartref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp@@a{chapter}%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \ref{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\temp@@b{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}}%
    \ifx\temp@@b\temp@@a
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{Chapter \zref@extract{#1}{default}/Part \zref@extract{#1}{partinfo}}%%
    \else
    \ref{#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{AAA}    
\chapter{Uno} \zlabel{chap:uno}
\part{BBB}    \label{part:bbb}
\chapter{Due} \zlabel{chap:due}

\clearpage

A comparison between \chappartref{chap:uno} and \chappartref{chap:due} \dots

On the other hand \chappartref{part:bbb} produces something different!

\end{document}
```

**Next update** With German translations for some counters

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\usepackage[user,counter,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,ngerman]{cleveref}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_zaehlernamen_deutsch_prop

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_tail:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_uppercase:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn {Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn {Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn {Nxx}

\newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]{%
  \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str {#1}%
  \str_uppercase:x {\str_head:N \l_tmpa_str}\str_tail:V {\l_tmpa_str}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\StoreCounterNameMap}{+m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {/} {##1}
    \prop_gput:Nxx \g_zaehlernamen_deutsch_prop { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}} { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
  }
}

\cs_new:Npn \GetNameFromCounter #1{%
  \prop_item:Nx \g_zaehlernamen_deutsch_prop {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\makeatletter


\newif\if@hyperrefloaded
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \global\@hyperrefloadedtrue
  }{
    \global\@hyperrefloadedfalse
  }
}


\zref@newprop{partinfo}{\thepart}
\zref@newprop{equationinfo}{\theequation}
\zref@addprops{main}{partinfo,equationinfo}

\newcommand{\partreferenceformat}[1]{%
  \GetNameFromCounter{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}}\ \zref@extract{#1}{default}/\GetNameFromCounter{part} \zref@extract{#1}{partinfo}%
}

\newcommand{\pref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp@@a{part}%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \Cref{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\temp@@b{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}}%
    \ifx\temp@@b\temp@@a
    \Cref{#1}%
    \else
    \if@hyperrefloaded
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\partreferenceformat{#1}}%
    \else
    \partreferenceformat{#1}%
    \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \endgroup
}

%Special command for zequationlabel
\newcommand{\zequationlabel}[1]{%
  \label{#1}%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{}{%
    \zref@setcurrent{anchor}{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}\relax}%
  }%
  \zref@setcurrent{counter}{equation}%
  \zref@setcurrent{default}{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \zlabel{#1}%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\StoreCounterNameMap{
  part/Teil, 
  chapter/Kapitel, 
  section/Abschnitt,
  subsection/Unterabschnitt,
  subsubsection/Unterunterabschnitt, % ;-)
  paragraph/Paragraf,
  subparagraph/Kleiner Paragraf,
  figure/Abbildung,
  table/Tabelle,
  equation/Gleichung
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{AAA}    
\chapter{Uno} \zlabel{chap:uno}

\begin{align}
  E&=mc^{2} \zequationlabel{Einstein} \\%
  E^{2} &= m^{2} c^{4} + p^{2} c^{2} \zequationlabel{Einstein2}
\end{align}

\section{Foo section} \zlabel{sec:foo}
\part{BBB} \label{part:bbb}
\chapter{Due} \zlabel{chap:due}



\blindtext[5]

\begin{align}
  E&=mc^{2} \zequationlabel{Einstein3}%
\end{align}


\getrefbykeydefault{Einstein}{anchor}


\clearpage

Hier ist ein kleiner Vergleich zwischen \pref{chap:uno} und \pref{chap:due}, oder zum Beispiel \pref{sec:foo}, bzw. \pref{Einstein} bzw. \pref{Einstein2}\dots

Wird nicht \verb!\zlabel! verwendet, dann liefert \verb!\pref! ganz einfach den cleveref-Namen, z.B: \pref{part:bbb}.

Und weil es so schön ist: \pref{Einstein3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also can't upload images due  to the imgur problem at the moment

Comment: I think this approach is going in the right direction, but my question, wasn't perfect asked. I want the normal behaviour for ref a any command, like chapter, section, etc. and insert after any of these commands the part.

Comment: @duichwer: In fact, it was not asked correctly. I think the answer can be changed, however.

Comment: Thanks, the result, looks ecactly what I expected. How can i get the text of `\zref@extract{#1}{counter}` translated into the german Options like Kapitel odr Abschnitt?

Comment: @duichwer: Nicht ohne viel Mühe ;-) Dafür existiert keine direkte Übersetzung.

Comment: @duichwer: Bitte das Update am Ende der Antwort beachten, die Verallgemeinerung auf andere Zählernamen ist recht einfach, siehe `\StoreCounterNameMap`, allerdings ist der `equation` - Zähler mit `zref` problematisch, dafür benötigt man "Gewalt" und einen eigenen Befehl. Der Link springt für Gleichungen etwas tiefer als die Gleichungsnummer.

Comment: @duichwer: Ich habe eine neue Version hochgeladen -- die Links funktionieren jetzt korrekt auch für den Gleichungszähler.

Comment: Hufper Wow. Your answer is really awesome. Is there any good documentation for the commands/package that you used to define those methods like `getNameFromCounter`?.. Maybe in German?

Comment: @duichwer: No, the parts with `\ExplSyntaxOn... \ExplSyntaxOff` is the considered to be the 'new' (cough!!!!) LaTeX 3 syntax -- there is no German documentation as far as I know. I it used to simplify often needed programming tasks in LaTeX (2e). See the documentation of `interface3.pdf` (`texdoc interface3` on commandline, for example). It's very tricky for new users to TeX and I don't claim I am do use it correctly in any occasion

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that the `\mychref` macro takes two arguments: here, they're labels of parts and chapters, but they could be anything, really.

```
\documentclass{report} % use a document class that provides "\chapter" macro
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
% Custom macro for composite cross-references
% Input ordering: part label, chapter label
% Output ordering: "Chapter" <number> "slash" "Part" <number>
\newcommand\mychref[2]{\Cref{#2}/\Cref{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\part{AAA}    \label{part:aaa}
\chapter{Uno} \label{chap:uno}
\part{BBB}    \label{part:bbb}
\chapter{Due} \label{chap:due}

\clearpage

A comparison between \mychref{part:aaa}{chap:uno} and \mychref{part:bbb}{chap:due} \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: I seem to be unable at the moment to upload a screenshot; I'll try again in a little while.

Comment: Who downvoted this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I have a hunch it's the very same person who downvoted two of my answers yesterday -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355744/5001 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355858/5001. That person must be getting a real rush of satisfaction from performing these oh-so-courageous downvotes...

Comment: One downvote was 'equalized' already, I voted for both ... yes, we have courageous downvoters here....

Comment: By the way, that answer on the cross-referencing packages is really great (that one you got a badge today for ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :-) (It's my fifth great-answer gold badge. Yay!)

Comment: Well-deserved... I don't even have a Guru - Badge yet