# change the default link of \ref{} in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

My document has chapters and sections. When I refer to sections in the same chapter I write `\ref{section_label}` when I refer to section in a different chapter I write `\ref{chapter_label}.\ref{section_label}`. On paper this has the desired effect.

Unfortunately, `hyperref` produce (of course) two different links in place o one. So replace the latter reference with

```
\hyperref[section_label]{\ref{chapter_label}.\ref{section_label}}
```

This produces the desired behavior in some viewer (Okular, Evince) but it has no effect on others (PDF.js).

I don't think the 'hack' above is a correct use of `hyperref`. Any suggestion?

Comment: did you check  `cleverref` or `varioref`?

Comment: Not a solution, but I really find it confusing to mix and match the reference. You should be consistent and use the same notation throughout your paper, possibly with `varioref` which integrates the page number in the reference, or with the customizations of `cleveref`

Comment: Something like here?   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356248/renumbering-chapter-after-part-include-part-number-as-suffix-in-cross-reference or here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353491/how-to-show-also-the-name-of-the-parent-counter-with-cleveref/353536?s=26|0.0000#353536 ?

Comment: I'd say `\ref*{chapter_label}.\ref{section_label}`

Comment: Why do you want that? Doesn't `\ref{section_label}` already contain the chapter number?

Answer (score 3):

Normally formatting is done by `\label` (actually `\refstepcounter`).  One could use multiple labels depending on how one wanted the reference to look.  This uses the same `\mylabel` macro used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/refer-to-the-name-of-an-equation-while-a-list-of-equations-is-generated-using/237126?s=1%7C0.6233#237126).

Hyperref uses its own labels which can be found using `\getrefbykeydefault`.  Also, `\ref` is protected (will not expand until printed), so if you want to use it in a macro you need to use `\getrefnumber` instead.  See refcount manual.

I threw in egreg's solution for comparison.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% non-standard definition

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}%
  {\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]% #1=name, #2 = contents
    {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}%
      {\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{}}}}}%
  {\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]% #1=name, #2 = contents
    {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\getrefanchor}[1]% #1 = label
  {\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{Doc-Start}}

\begin{document}

One can use \ref*{chapter}.\ref{section}, \ref{mylabel} or 
\hyperlink{\getrefanchor{section}}{\getrefnumber{chapter}.\getrefnumber{section}}.

\chapter{chapter}\label{chapter}
\section{dummy}
\section{section}\label{section}\mylabel{mylabel}{\thechapter.\thesection}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg 's solution is what I was looking for. Thank you!